# Bundle dependency jars into output jar

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm working with an application that loads plugins as jars from a directory. The plugins are to have the following layout:

```
plugin.myplugin.jar/
  com.xxx.xxx/<compiled classes for plugin>
  META-INF/MANIFEST.MF (defines the main entry point for the plugin)
  lib/
     com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-core-2.3.1.jar
     ...
     ...
     com.netflix.rxjava.rxjava-core-0.16.1.jar
     ...
     <all dependencies used by the plugin in their original jar format>
```

I can do this manually by using the sbt-native-packager plugin to produce the top-level plugin.myplugin.jar and then copying the jars from target/universal/stage/lib into the lib directory within plugin.myplugin.jar using something like 7-zip. Doing this manually works... but I'm trying to automate this task though and currently I am at a bit of a loss as to how to override an sbt-native-packager task or write my own to do this. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you looked at http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/DetailedTopics/universal.html#mapping-examples and http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Mapping-Files.html? Seems like something you're trying to do.

Comment: Taking a look -- looks promising. I've also found https://github.com/retronym/sbt-onejar which has not been actively maintained but I think I can adapt to fit my needs.

Comment: If you like sbt-onejar you could also have a look at the excellent sbt-assembly: https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly

It does the same things and it is maintained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you could achieve what you want with pure SBT 0.13.x (the example should work for older versions in general, but maybe you'd have to use different operators).

#### build.sbt

```
import Path.flat

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-core" % "2.3.1",
  "com.netflix.rxjava" % "rxjava-core" % "0.16.1"
  // maybe more dpendencies
)

packageOptions in (Compile, packageBin) +=
        Package.ManifestAttributes("PluginMainClass" -> "com.xxx.xxx.Class")

// this will copy all managed jars to the ./lib in your jar
mappings in (Compile, packageBin) ++= {
  val cp = (managedClasspath in Compile).value.files
  cp pair flatRebase("/lib")
}

// this will move all your compiled classes to folder ./com.xxx.xxx in your jar
mappings in (Compile, packageBin) ++= {
  val compiledClasses = (products in Compile).value ** "*.class"
  val classDirectoryBase = (classDirectory in Compile).value
  compiledClasses pair rebase(classDirectoryBase, "com.xxx.xxx")
}
```

You can then use `package` to build the jar. In the example as above the jar will look like this:

```
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
      301  2014-05-09 20:13   META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
        0  2014-05-09 20:13   /lib/
  7126003  2013-09-27 11:44   /lib/scala-library.jar
   197986  2013-12-28 02:01   /lib/jackson-core-2.3.1.jar
   663553  2014-01-15 08:17   /lib/rxjava-core-0.16.1.jar
---------                     -------
  7987843                     5 files
```

And the manifest will look like this

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Implementation-Vendor: default
Implementation-Title: q-23553321
Implementation-Version: 0.1-SNAPSHOT
Implementation-Vendor-Id: default
PluginMainClass: com.xxx.xxx.Class // MAIN CLASS OF THE PLUGIN
Specification-Vendor: default
Specification-Title: q-23553321
Specification-Version: 0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

#### Edit

> Is it possible to get the compiled classes in a multi module build
>   though? IE if I have /modules/X,Y,Z and I want the compiled classes
>   from those projects bundled under "com.xxx.xxx" in the artifact?

The general answer is yes, if the classes are unique. To do that you can use [Scopes](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Tasks.html#scopefilter). In the `build.sbt`, replace the mappings for classes with the following:

```
// define the configuration axis
val anyProjectsCompile = ScopeFilter(inAnyProject, inConfigurations(Compile))

// we want to have class directory and products together to use rebase in the next step
val classDirectoryProducts = Def.task {
  (classDirectory.value, products.value)
}

mappings in (Compile, packageBin) ++= {
  classDirectoryProducts.all(anyProjectsCompile).value.flatMap { case (classDir, prods) =>
    val compiledClasses = (prods ** "*.class").get
    compiledClasses pair rebase(classDir, "com.xxx.xxx")
  }
}
```

Comment: This is almost exactly what I've been trying to do @lpiepiora. Is it possible to get the compiled classes in a multi module build though? IE if I have /modules/X,Y,Z and I want the compiled classes from those projects bundled under "com.xxx.xxx" in the artifact?

Comment: For now I've added
    classDirectory in Compile <<= baseDirectory apply ( _ / ".." / ".." / "target" / "classes" )

to my submodule project definitions to drop the classes in the top level output directory. PRobably not the greatest idea but seems to be working.

Comment: @steveturner look at my updated answer, I think it would scale better. The idea is to use scopes to find right files.

Comment: This worked great. Thanks for your help! Instead of a rebase I'm doing  'compiledClasses pair relativeTo(classDir) '